# convergence of $\sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log n)^2}$in the log test and conditions for success

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> $$\sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log n)^2}.$$

I think there's the ratio test and when I tried it got stuck

****Important, while this question was answwered very good, just had a concern with one of the answers so I JUST put a comment in and would appreciate if someone would be able to address it

Thanks!***

Comment: Use `$\sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log n)^2}$` to show $\sum_{n = 2}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log n)^2}.$ Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: In the long run, $(\log n)^2\lt n$.

Answer (score 3):

Use [Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test): you want to test the convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_n
$$
where $a_n=1/(\log n)^2$ which is a positive and decreasing sequence; thus the above series converges iff $\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}2^na_{2^n}$ does.

But
$$
2^na_{2^n}=\frac{2^n}{(\log2^n)^2}=\frac{2^n}{n^2\log^22}\stackrel{n\to+\infty}{\longrightarrow}+\infty
$$
thus $\sum_{n=2}^{+\infty}2^na_{2^n}$ diverge.

Answer (score 2):

Comparison test and Integral test also can be used. Since $n > \log n$ For all $n \ge 2$, Following inequality holds:
$$
0\le\frac{1}{n\log n} < \frac{1}{(\log n)^2}
$$
Then $f(x)=\frac{1}{x\log x}$ monotonely decreases on $[2,\infty)$ and
\begin{align}
\int_2^{\infty} \frac{dx}{x \log x}&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\int_{\ln 2}^{\ln N}\frac{1}{t}dt\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\left[\ln t\right]_{\ln 2}^N\\
&=\lim_{N\to\infty}(\ln(\ln N)-\ln(\ln 2))\\
&=\infty
\end{align}
Thus, $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n\log n}$ diverges by integral test. Therefore $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\log n)^2}$ diverges by comparison test.

Comment: I am having trouble understanding why you compared the series to 1/(n log(n)) 

WHy did you not compare this to 1/n(log(n)^2 and just use the p series test to test if it was convergent or divergent

Comment: Because $\frac{1}{n(\log n)^2}\le \frac{1}{(\log n)^2}$ and so we can't apply comparison test to show given series converges. p-series is $\sum \frac{1}{n^p}$, $\log$ is not included.

Comment: still do not get why you cannot compare it since I even looked at the comparison test and this didnt make sense

Comment: Remark the statement of comparison test: Given two sequence $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$, If $0\le a_n \le b_n$ and $\sum b_n$ converges, then $\sum a_n$ converges, and if $0\le b_n \le a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ diverges, then $\sum a_n$ diverges. If you want to use $\frac{1}{n(\log n)^2}$ to show that given series converges, then you have to show that  $\frac{1}{n(\log n)^2}$ is bigger than $\frac{1}{(\log n)^2}$. However, it is false.